# How to create a registration-free installer with WiX (manifest-based)

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I'd like to create an installer package to install registration-free COM components (with manifest files included). This would be more or less a self-extracting archive to place some files in a target directory given as commandline argument, but it would also need to check or install some other redistributables like VC++ or DirectX.

The package is supposed to be used in another applications's installer as some kind of redistributable package itself. It should not be registered in the "Program and Features" dialog of Windows but has to be removed with the application. Ideally there should be no changes to the Windows registry.

So far I haven't been very successful. Can anyone please provide me with some hints regarding this use case?

Comment: To be honest, in the 11 years since RegFree COM came out I've never had a single project that used it.  Harvesting COM metadata from DLL's and authoring them into MSI is very simple, reliable and elegant.  RegFree COM is a solution to a problem that doesn't exist IMO.  I'd focus on eliminating COM first rather then making it even more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got about a dozen different questions in that one question. Start with just creating a simple MSI that successfully installs your files and your manifest.  Create a COM client to test it.  You can also put AppSearch and LaunchConditions in your MSI to detect your dependencies and not allow installation if they are missing.

That's about all you should have to do for this simple question.  As for the other questions.... if you are a redistributable and someone else is silently installing you then it's their job to handle the installation of the other redistributables.  Also if they don't want you listed in Programs and Features they can pass the [ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)=1 to your installer and you won't be listed.   If they want to uninstall you when they uninstall themselves, that's their problem not yours.

Comment: I don't have any problems with COM. My question is regarding the installation process. I'm going to look into the ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT property. I just wondered how the app's installer knows what to remove if my installer doesn't support its own uninstallation.

Comment: ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT doesn't prevent your installer from having an uninstall, it just prevents it from being listed in ARP.  msiexec /x capability is still there.  The expectation becomes that the parent product that installed you will have an uninstall routine that calls your uninstall when appropriate. (For example see WiX Burn Bootstrappers)

Answer (score 0):

If you are really creating a redistributable to be used by other products, sometimes a merge module is the appropriate solution. They build their MSI files and include your merge module.

Otherwise, reg-free COM is in theory an easy install because you're just installing manifest files and Dlls etc. However I don't understand how that could be used by other apps because (IIRC) a client app exe needs your manifest and Dll in their install folder, so how can they do that when they are not installed yet? Or even if they are installed how can you find them? So that goes back to the merge module idea so they include your merge module and install an exe, your manifest and your Dll in the same location. When they uninstall so do your files.

Comment: I don't understand the question. They just extract your manifest file and DLLs in their program directory and reference your manifest in their own.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't understood your plan properly, but "extract into their program directory" seems odd. You've got a zip file? Or they run your setup and somehow they direct it to install in their app folder, then their app runs and uses your files? So they install their app first, then yours? It's difficult to say what the best approach might be without knowing the actual steps in your planned deployment process.

Comment: Well that's just how regfree COM works: they put the COM components into their application's folder instead of installing them globally. That's why I wrote the redist. installer would be more or less a self-extracting archive.